Problem with second monitor
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am having a problem with the second monitor "appearance". Anything that's on the second monitor looks with good quality but, everything is bigger. The pointer going from my laptop to the monitor gets bigger, the home folder is much bigger etc.
The primary display is 2880x1800.
The HDMI display is 1920x1080.
I have my NVIDIA drivers up to date.
I've tried fixing this 2 ways:

through settings: in display, changed to fractional scaling but applying the change to one of the monitors affects the other one as well. So that doesn't work.
xrandr: i've tried to find the right configuration but couldn't

Here is what the config file looks at the moment. With this I have the looks stated in the introduction of the problem
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output eDP-1 --primary --mode 2880x1800 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output DP-2 --off --output DP-3 --off --output DP-4 --off --output HDMI-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2880x0 --rotate normal

Scale for the primary monitor is 1x1 and for the 2x2 at the moment.
Running xrandr:
eDP-1 connected primary 2880x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 312mmx195mm
2880x1800    120.00 +  60.00*
HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+2880+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mmx299mm
1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
I have tried changing the scale but it would never resolve the issue, i would only see part of the screen and the pointer did not but the real position of the mouse.
I've tried a few other things suggested by ChatGPT like "Use the cvt command to generate a modeline for the desired resolution (3840x2160 at 60Hz):" and tried out arandr but nothing worked.
I'd greatly appreciate some help with his problem.
